# iptables: aren't these docs wrong?

Tags: linux, iptables, documentation

I've been looking at two references for `iptables` documentation, and both *appear* to be wrong in some very important details.

However, being new to `iptables`, I'm not fully sure, hence this post.

1. [Reference 1 - Iptables Tutorial 1.2.2](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#TRAVERSINGGENERAL) : In the figure that immediately follows `Table 6-3 Forwarded Packets`, shouldn't the arrow coming out of `filter/FORWARD` be going straight to `mangle/POSTROUTING`, since the the routing decision to forward the packet already stands made? *The text of Table 6-3 also seems to suggest this.*
2. [Reference 2 - Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) : In the `Network Layer` - `OUTPUT PATH` cell, the first `routing decision` is correctly followed by `raw/OUTPUT`, `mangle/OUTPUT`, `nat/OUTPUT`, `filter/OUTPUT`. However, shouldn't there be one more `routing decision` between `filter/OUTPUT` and `mangle/POSTROUTING`, since a `nat` table processing must necessarily be followed by a routing decision? Also, not sure what the `reroute check` box is doing before the `nat/OUTPUT` box!

Could someone please confirm my understanding, or correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: The mangle table could mark packets with fwmark, which can be used in routing rules to influence the routing. Hence the routing decision needs to be made again.

Comment: ok, in that case, the text is inaccurate/inconsistent with other mentions of "routing decision" in the 3 tables.